# What happened to YouTube download URLs?

Tags: youtube

**Note: This question is about download URLs, not software. The question "[How do I download a YouTube video?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video)" deals with software.**

What **exactly** changed for YouTube download URLs a few days ago? How should YouTube download URLs be formed now?

The following URL used to work (downloading [this Flash video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYW50F42ss8) to disk) but no longer works since the change:

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video.php?video_id=DYW50F42ss8&t=vjVQa1PpcFPDxa83Hr1_9pftRUWdsMyJ10a2o8QZvIs=
```

---

Note: the following information is only to **illustrate the problem**. I am only interested in the information about how to form download URLs.

This change affected quite a few tools. Here are leads from some Firefox plug-in homepages:

From [Video DownloadHelper 4.7.4](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3006/), 2010-07-22:

> "As many of the users noticed, 
>       Video DownloadHelper does not work well on YouTube since 
>       today. This is due to a very recent change at YouTube. 
>       We made a fix that seems to work ok. "

From [Easy YouTube Video Downloader 3.4](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10137/), 2010-07-24:

> "Please update to latest version 3.5 
>       in sandbox to get it working again with latest Youtube 
>       changes"

From [YouTube Downloader](http://youtubedownload.altervista.org/), 2010-07-24:

> "YouTube has updated their website in a way that breaks YouTube Downloader 2.5.6 and older. We are working on version 2.6 which fixes this problem."

---

Related: "[How do I download a YouTube video?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video)". Some of those tools may be broken now!

Comment: I don't see any change in the source code. Maybe it's a slight change, but the `videoplayback` link is still there.

Comment: @Vortico: do you have a **direct** URL to that source code?

Comment: (Placeholder for Andrew's comment: "you forgot to say what the change was and the code solution.")

Comment: OH! Sorry about that, I misunderstood. What I meant to say is that you can still download the FLV or MP4 (HTML 5) by opening the source code of the video page and searching `videoplayback`.

Comment: For example, the link to the FLV of the video you posted is http://v12.lscache4.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?ip=0.0.0.0&sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Calgorithm%2Cburst%2Cfactor%2Coc%3AU0dXRVBPVl9FSkNNN19ISVpF&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=34&ipbits=0&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1280048400&key=yt1&signature=504828E84653745CED079895E1EF81F01EF1AD33.1FCC01F8FACF4139FCB815468B480E73A0666047&factor=1.25&id=0d85b9d05e36b2cf

Comment: http://www.youtube-nocookie.com exists (note the "nocookie" part) and a tracert leads to almost the same server. Perhaps this could be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

I am unsure what changed, but I suspect YouTube changed their URLs so you can not get a video without matching cookies. This prevents 3rd party sites from showing you ads and giving you download links.

I can tell you this link (pasted at the very bottom), which I got from your video, WORKS for me. However if I paste it in my other instance of Firefox (which has different cookies for the site) this link does NOT work.

I suggest using a userscript. I like [YouTube Enhancer](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/33042).

If you need to do this in code I do see the link(s?) in `var swfConfig =`

> http://v12.lscache4.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?ip=0.0.0.0&sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Calgorithm%2Cburst%2Cfactor%2Coc%3AU0dXRVFRTl9FSkNNN19JS1JB&fexp=903205%2C906501&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=34&ipbits=0&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1280160000&key=yt1&signature=2F2BB59B9BA3E6AB62CEE47F597D7A4D96002893.03196019F468211FAA4E492F7F5B1951951AEAF9&factor=1.25&id=0d85b9d05e36b2cf&title=Tom%20Lehrer%20CHEMISTRY%20element%20song

to make it easy for me to read I did a full escape using [this handy script](http://www.web-code.org/coding-tools/javascript-escape-unescape-converter-tool.html).

> http://v12.lscache4.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?ip=0.0.0.0&sparams=id,expire,ip,ipbits,itag,algorithm,burst,factor,oc:U0dXRVFRTl9FSkNNN19JS1JB&fexp=903205,906501&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=34&ipbits=0&burst=40&sver=3&expire=1280160000&key=yt1&signature=2F2BB59B9BA3E6AB62CEE47F597D7A4D96002893.03196019F468211FAA4E492F7F5B1951951AEAF9&factor=1.25&id=0d85b9d05e36b2cf&title=Tom
>   Lehrer CHEMISTRY element song

Answer (score 0):

I found another great browser script to use with GreaseMonkey.

It is called **YouTube Links**.
It is available [here](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/5566-youtube-links) ([archived](http://archive.li/APGlv#7%25)).
And here is the [source code](http://web.archive.org/web/20190216031759/https://greasyfork.org/scripts/5566-youtube-links/code/YouTube%20Links.user.js).

I have chosen this, because it works without derouting to an external downloading webapp.

[image]