# How to increase the volume on certain YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

Most videos on YouTube are loud enough and I can hear them perfectly well, but some have got the volume down too low even with the YouTube volume slider on max and the PC volume set to maximum too. In theory it must be possible to increase the volume, but does such software actually exist?

Comment: Is there any way, I can increase or decrease the quality of the video on VLC when streaming from youtube?

Comment: Just use "Volume Master" Chrome extension (up to 600 % volume boost for any given tab), problem solved: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/volume-master/jghecgabfgfdldnmbfkhmffcabddioke

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you have VLC player, you don't have to download the video. Just open VLC → **File** → **Open Network**, paste the YouTube URL and click **Open**. Doing this will stream the YouTube video through VLC, allowing you to use the VLC audio settings.

Comment: Does not seem to work for vlc 2.5.1. YouTube automatically change the http to https, this may be the problem.

Comment: On OS X, use ⌘+↑ to increase the volume beyond what the slider allows. I guess a similar combination will work on Linux/Windows.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on VLC version "3.0.4-1ubuntu0.2". Example video at https://youtu.be/8Bmcgn2RBGI that had been recorded with very low audio. Unfortunately, I had to download the video (very slowly? why?) using Firefox's Flash Video Downloader 16.2.8 at : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-video-downloader/?src=search

Answer (score 3):

One non-optimal possibility is [download](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video) the video and then play it in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) which has the ability to increase the volume up to 800% (using the mousewheel on the volume slider).

Comment: BTW, for me it only goes to 200%! I have installed the current version just now.

Comment: I'm also seeing a max volume of 200% using VLC version 2.1.5 on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

There is a browser add-on for Google Chrome and Firefox available and actively maintained as of 2019:

[Audio Equalizer and Amplifier](https://add0n.com/audio-equalizer.html)

Apparently it's not just for YouTube, but that's what I needed something for a few years ago, and that's what I needed again now. This time I found it and it's working for me right now.

It has a pre-amplifier and also a graphic equalizer. I'm only using the amp.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably flash is accessing you audio at the driver level so the only change you could make would be there i.e. using a driver that lets you route the audio through processing (It might be worth looking into this http://jackaudio.org/ I'm not sure this will do do the job).

Perhaps HTML5s video tag will open up the ability to do this sort of thing with a JavaScript or a browser plug-in

Answer (score 1):

I use this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(()=>{if(!!window.__volumeForced)return;window.__volumeForced=true;let forceVolume=()=>{document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].volume=1;setTimeout(forceVolume,50);};forceVolume();})();
```

Apparently, YouTube videos are normalized, so the video volume is not 1.0, it ranges from 0.4 to 0.7 on some videos.

I explained this [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/103665)