# Download a VideoPress video

Tags: video, flash, video-download

How do I download a video stored on [VideoPress](http://videopress.com/)?

Example: on http://get2business.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/effektiv-og-malrettet-jobsøgning/ there are two embedded videos. Looking at the source it appears a Flash video for the first video is stored on videopress.com with these specifics:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 

<param name="flashvars" value="guid=iOIltixO&amp;javascriptid=video0" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to download using any [flash video downloader](http://www.google.co.in/search?ie=UTF-8&q=flash+video+downloader) or simply use [FlashGet](http://www.flashget.com/download.htm).

**Update:**
See [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2781/4008) to see more flash video downloader.

> [How do I download a youtube video?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2781/4008)