# How can I watch a YouTube video in slow motion?

Tags: youtube

I have been watching a fast-moving video that I'd really love to dissect in slow motion (half or quarter speed; frame-by-frame isn't necessary in this case). Is there a quick and easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to join the [YouTube HTML 5 beta program](http://www.youtube.com/html5) and have a compatible browser.

The playback options are as follows

[image: 2x, 1.5, Normal, 1/2, 1/4]

Make sure to inspect all [restrictions](http://www.youtube.com/html5) as not all YouTube videos can be played via HTML5.

Comment: Lovely. I like it!

Comment: YouTube API allows suggestedRate player parameter so you can slow to 75%, 50%, 25% etc.using Youtube IFrame API call setPlayBackRate(), getPlayBackRates() available for a given video. youtube.com/watch?v=B1GFzd7KYfI#t=12m03s.
NOTE: As per this video on soundslice you can ONLY slow down videos which are encoded to support this video using HTML5 player

Comment: This feature has since been made available in the default YouTube player for all videos

Answer (score 2):

First [download the video](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2781).
Then watch it with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and use the slow motion feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible unless you download the entire video on your machine. YouTube's Flash Player does not have such an option.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, [NetVideoHunter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/netvideohunter-video-downloade/) → [FLV Converter](http://www.flv-converter.org/) → [Windows Media Player](http://www.ehow.com/how_6916841_do-motion-windows-media-player.html) is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add slow after the word youtube in a youtube link, and you'll get redirected to the page that slows it down. :) The link then contains youtubeslow.com instead of youtube.com. :)

.. Or just go to the page([www.youtubeslow.com](http://www.youtubeslow.com)) to [watch a youtube video in slow motion.](http://www.youtubeslow.com) :)

Comment: The site is quite brute-force. 
The play-pause method is being used here rather primitive.
You could achieve the same thing by keeping the space bar pressed. The only difference is you can control the slow down to 1/4 or 1/2 speed here.

Answer (score 1):

[www.watchframebyframe.com](http://www.watchframebyframe.com) supports half and quarter speed (frame-by-frame and precision timing as well!).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use www.pausehouse.com. It's a really cool website, that lets you change the slow motion speed of YouTube videos, repeat selection, and even flip the image. Thus you can learn moves from YouTube videos with ease.

Comment: Thanks for the link. rowvid.com is a similar site, and I think it's a little nicer interface for frame by frame.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to much.  Just download the Chrome extension from EmbedPlus.  You can learn more here:

[How to watch YouTube video in slow motion using EmbedPlus](http://www.embedplus.com/)

and 
[EmbedPlus Chrome Extension for YouTube Slow Motion](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/embedplus-for-youtube/nalagllbblcejhhmeffeiofclifnpbeo)

Comment: It seems like embedplus is also using the play-pause method, which is rather primitive. You could achieve the same thing by keeping the space bar pressed. The only difference is you can control the slow down to 1/4 or 1/2 speed here.  

YouTube API allows suggestedRate player parameter so you can slow to 75%, 50%, 25% etc.using Youtube IFrame API call setPlayBackRate(), getPlayBackRates() available for a given video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1GFzd7KYfI#t=12m03s  

As per this video on soundslice you can  slow down videos which are encoded to support this video using HTML5 player.