# Downloading YouTube playlist

Tags: youtube, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I download a YouTube video?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video)

I'm looking for an app which downloads the playlist videos one after another from YouTube.

For example in the webpage [top documentary films for story of science](http://topdocumentaryfilms.com/story-of-science/), the YouTube video has 36 videos in a playlist. I would like an app to download all the 36 videos automatically.