# Download YouTube videos when they are split

Tags: youtube, video, download

Recently, some YouTube videos are downloaded part by part (2 MB) to the browser and played. So, I am unable to download such videos directly within my browser using Addons.

[image: YouTube_split_2mb]

Are there any alternative ways to download the whole video within the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are using FlashGot addon for Firefox. FlashGot determines the direct link to the video and makes it available for download as soon as you start viewing a YouTube video; and each time you step to a different point inside a video, FlashGot creates another link for that split part. Your best bet would be to use the *first* link FlashGot provides.

If you are still looking for alternatives to FlashGot, see the answers to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video).

Comment: No, I am not stepping to another point in the video manually. I clicked the play button only once. The video is not split by the addon. YouTube itself is sending the video by 2mb part. Even the first link in the FlashGot was just 2MB.

Comment: What is the URL of that video?

Comment: this is the URL http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aosUrZYJeeI but today when I played the video in YouTube site, the FlashGot link points to 16MB. But when played inside a Facebook profile (embed player), it is 2MB part.

Comment: As you say, there is no problem when you play the video on YouTube. So the video split problem is related to Facebook. I suggest you download the videos using the original Youtube pages.