# How to save buffered You Tube video

Tags: youtube, download, video-streaming

I am watching some video lectures on You Tube (licensed under Creative Commons - Don't know the version but I have right to copy).. So, after watching (streaming), how to download the buffered content..

I guess it would be on Browser Cache! but how to get it on HDD?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video

Answer (score 1):

You can try `youtube-dl` - a python-script.

http://youtube-dl.org/

If you use a little script-magic, you can easily make it download a list of videos or all the videos in a channel.

EDIT: No need for script-magic.  There are options allowing you to specify a file with video-URLs.  And if given the URL of a playlist or a channel, it'll download all the videos there.  Despite the name, `youtube-dl` works on numerous video-sites.

Answer (score -1):

There are a plethora of Firefox and Chrome add-ons that you can use to download flv (Flash Video) from the web, including youtube. I would start there.

Answer (score -1):

You can view the cache of Firefox (unfortunately only <22.0) with [CacheViewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/hu/firefox/addon/cacheviewer/) and look for large files.