# How do I download a YouTube video (in 2019)?

Tags: youtube, download, video-download

I know this question has technically been asked before ([How do I download a YouTube video?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2781/114128)), **but that was 9 years ago**!

A lot has changed, and in fact many of the answers no longer operate the way they did when the answers were written. This is because almost all of the answers are about 9 years old as well, with the newest still being >2 years old (and having 0 votes). We need an update!

**My question:** So what are some accessible and *safe* ways to download YouTube videos in 2019?

Preferably, I would like to know free options that I can trust, and I would prefer add-ons for Firefox or Chrome. However, all trustworthy options are valid answers.

---

<sup>I would prefer answers with suggestions that don't require or contain subscriptions, external services, external apps, helper apps, payments, adware, crippleware, or malware. The simpler the solution, the better!</sup>